# How do I count the number of running threads (pthreads)?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads, posix

If I search for counting the number of threads an application has, all the answers involve external programs like `top`. I want to count the threads within the application itself.

I can't add code at the point of thread creation because it happens inside an immutable library.

I can't read `/proc`.

It's a C/pthreads program running on a few different Unices.

Comment: "man ps" and look at 'thread'. For example "ps -TF -p $pid", you can run with via ssh if you need remote control I guess.

Comment: This has to be done by my application, not by invoking another application.

Comment: Pthreads doesn't have an API for counting threads, it doesn't even guarantee that you get more than one kernel thread.  You could `ptrace(2)` your process but that's a hack you would only use for debugging.

Comment: A major point of the design of pthreads is that it can be completely transparent (to the rest of the program) whether a function is implemented using multiple threads or not. If you're trying to count your threads, you're probably doing something very wrong. For threads you create yourself, you can safely count them with a semaphore (post it when they start, wait it when they exit) or a counter you modify under control of a mutex.

Comment: "Completely transparent"? I don't buy that. That would imply no critical sections, no `gettid`...

Comment: Yes, completely transparent. The standard library's `qsort`, for example, could be implemented with multiple threads, and the caller would not be aware of this without calling `pthread_self` or `pthread_getspecific` from within the comparison callback. Similarly, `free` might use an extra thread to manage and coalesce freed blocks in the background. If you have created **your own** threads, then yes, you must be aware of them and any necessary synchronization. But threads created by the standard library or third-party libraries are intended to be transparent to your application.

Comment: Dammit that's exactly what I don't want :-(

Comment: If you can phrase that as an answer with citations, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't read `/proc` you are a bit in trouble, unless your program communicate with another program which reads `/proc`

If you don't want to read `/proc` because of portability concerns, you might use a library which abstracts that a bit, like `libproc` does

Comment: Thanks for the libproc tip, but it won't work in this locked-down environment. Introducing a new library is a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a tiny wrapper for pthread_create that counts created threads and link against that wrapper after you linked against the immutable library.

Comment: But the library wouldn't call the wrapper...?

Comment: The library calls pthread_create. You can provide the pthread_create implementation during linking, either at link time or with the LD_PRELOAD trick known from dmalloc and friends.

Comment: @spraff, if you link with your own lib, it will be called.

Answer (score -1):

Use top -H. But chances are, if you can't read proc, top won't work anyway. If thats the case, there is no easy way and it would depend on your specific system.